# Any proper list of Mac firmware versions (Boot ROM versions) and the corresponding macOS version?

Tags: firmware

Any proper list of Mac firmware versions (Boot ROM versions) and the corresponding macOS version?

This can be useful if you receive a Mac with the storage damaged and the customer wants to have the same macOS version that was installed when the storage broke.

You’d start the mac with an external macOS volume and check the firmware version in System Information.

The official Apple article for this only lists the firmware that originally shipped with the Mac.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518

I found this one shows most, but doesn’t have a proper list of firmware version / corresponding macOS: 
https://browser.geekbench.com

Comment: formware and OS are not that connected. Only  the firmware that originally shipped with the Mac is defined.

Answer (score 6):

There is a blog from hoakley under "The Eclectic Light Company" webpage that tries to list the most recent firmware versions for different Macs and also tells with what OS update you can get them:

- *["Which EFI firmware should your Mac be using? (version 3)"](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/10/31/which-efi-firmware-should-your-mac-be-using-version-3/)*

There are also two earlier versions of that page:

- *["Which EFI firmware should your Mac be using? (version 2)"](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/06/27/which-efi-firmware-should-your-mac-be-using-version-2/)*
- *["Which EFI firmware should your Mac be using?"](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/10/04/which-efi-firmware-should-your-mac-be-using/)*

And the blog has been updated for more recent firmware versions and machines:

- ["Which EFI firmware should your Mac be using? (version 4)"](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/08/which-efi-firmware-should-your-mac-be-using-version-4/)

  ["Which EFI firmware should your Mac be using? (version 5)"](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/16/which-firmware-should-your-mac-be-using-version-5/)

  ["Which EFI firmware should your Mac be using? (version 6)"](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/09/02/which-firmware-should-your-mac-be-using-version-6/)